# How to get data attribute in table jquery when click btnfile by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7A9s.png)

help me...I wanna get data attribute from click button 'btnfile'

I can not get data attribute on button it created from jquery

you can click "enter image description here" for viewing picture
thank you

Comment: $(this).data('attribute_name');
OR
$(this).attr('data-attribute_name');
Button "data" attribute should be like <button data-attribute_name="1">

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `data method like so:

```
$('#btnfile').data('jpath');
```

Read [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for more information